# Unable to update Vue-Multiselect model with predefined object

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

Facing a small issue here with using vue-multiselect in order to set a predefined selected value on form edit. I've tried multiple different ways trying to get this to work and am currently at the stage where a predefined value is set, however whenever I try and manually update the form.newstype form attribute as seen below, the value does not change in the multiselect.

The desired result is to not use the @select method bound to the multiselect component and just rely on the model to update via 2-way binding, however my form.newstype doesn't seem to update. Any pointers or suggestions are most welcome. A solution would be a lifesaver.

Code same can be seen below.

```js
Vue.component('news-form', {
    mixins: [AppForm],
    props: ['newstypes', 'activetype'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            form: {
                title:  '' ,
                slug:  '' ,
                perex:  '' ,
                published_at:  '' ,
                enabled:  false ,
                newstype: '',
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{

        updateNewsType:function(newVal, id){
            console.log(newVal);
            this.form.newstype = newVal;

        }

    },
    created() {

        this.form.newstype = this.activetype;
    }

});
```

```html
<multiselect
                @select="updateNewsType"
                v-model="form.newstype"
                :options="newstypes"
                :multiple="false"
                track-by="type"
                label="type"
                tag-placeholder="{{ __('Select News Type') }}"
                placeholder="{{ __('News Type') }}">
</multiselect>
```

The console.log outputs the updated object, however the form.newstypes is not updated.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use `watch` to listen to any update in your selected value :

```
v-model="selected_news_type"

watch: {
     selected_news_type: function(value){
            console.log(value);
            this.form.newstype = value;   
}

}
```